# how scrapy work in dynamic start_urls repeatly

Tags: python, scrapy

here is the situation:

i have functionA that return a url list to crawl ,and after scrapy finish crawling,i want scrapy to (maybe restart) get a new url list from functionA and crawl them repeatly

what's proper way to realize it?can it realize only by scrapy and don't depend on other software?

when using the field start_urls,( like start_url=functionA() )it seems that get once and don't crawl repeatly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't really know how you are going to update your list that `functionA` gives, but this should work for what you want.

```
class MySpider(Spider):
    name = 'myspider'

    idle_time = 0
    def functionA(self):
        # returns urls

    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.functionA():
            yield Request(url, callback=self.parse)
        self.crawler.signals.connect(self.spider_idle,
                                     signal=signals.spider_idle)

    def spider_idle(self, spider):
        # called when the spider is `idle`, before finishing
        self.idle_time += 1
        if self.idle_time < 10: # how many times you want to recrawl?
            for url in self.functionA():
                yield Request(url, callback=self.parse)


    def parse(self, response):
        # parse your urls
```

Comment: thanks your answer!!!!!but there some problem :1. for url in self.getPricesUrl(self):TypeError: getPricesUrl() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)  then i remove the "self" in bracket 2. the signals is not defined(after from scrapy import signals it's ok   )  but i try scrapy crawl spider  it still run only one time

Comment: share the logs, as I told you, I don't know how you are reupdating your urls, so if they are the same the second time, maybe scrapy is filtering them.

Comment: hi ,i add the log ,can i  add the dont_filter=True in yield Request(url, callback=self.parse)  so that it can crawl the same url?

Comment: yes, and please update your question, not my answer :)

Comment: yaha ,sorry,i dont recognize it...!!!,but after add  dont_filter=True in both yield Request(url, callback=self.parse)  it still crawl only one time,maybe some problem in "" for url in self.getPricesUrl(self):""" of start_requests(self)?[TypeError: getPricesUrl() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)] and i remove the self in bracket

Comment: yeah remove that self when calling.

Comment: sorry,it is still not working ....maybe i need another way to realize my demand.....

Comment: it didn't repeat to crawl...but according to your thinking i find another way and it finally work!!!!!thank you all the same!!!![http://codeflippa.com/questions/28764083/run-new-spider-or-get-new-list-of-urls-for-scraping]